# Formatting files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

we have a customized file with an extension called .pjs. 
Any leads to provided support for format using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or when user click on save button inside Eclipse. I am looking for javascript style formatting for our customized files. The content of the file is like javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **pjs** to Eclipse's list of known file types:

   - **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations ->** Click the **Add...** button to the right of the **File types** list.
   - In the **Add File Type** dialog enter **`*.pjs`** in the **File type** field and click **OK**.
   - Verify that **`*.pjs`** is now shown in the list of **File types**.

[image]

2. Associate file type **pjs** with the JavaScript Editor:

   - Ensure the **`*.pjs`** entry you just added to the list of file types is selected.
   - Click the **Add...** button to the right of the **Associated Editors** field.
   - In the **Editor Selection** dialog select the *JavaScript Editor* entry and click **OK**.

[image]

3. Double-click some **`*.pjs`** project file to open it. It should open using the JavaScript Editor.
4. Ensure that the source is incorrectly formatted, then position the cursor anywhere over the source, right-click and select **Source -> Format** or  <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to see the *.pjs source reformatted.
5. Here is some trivial JavaScript you can use to verify that you can format a **`*.pjs`** file:

**`x(function(z) { });`**

should be reformatted as:

**`x(function(z) {
});`**

6. As a separate but related matter, I struggle to get Eclipse's JavaScript reformatting to do much, and the code sample above was carefully chosen, but I rarely use JavaScript so that may be my fault. However, see [Bug 357829 - Javascript formatter seems not to do anything](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357829).

Comment: I have tried this approach .But the problem is that it will not show compilation errors,auto fill ups and auto imports etc..